# How to check a field is null in an insert trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

How to verify in a trigger if before inserting data in a table and in a field nothing is inserted, that is, it is null. How can I check whether or not it is null in a trigger?

I have tried to validate it this way, but it is not entering the condition when the field is null.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_i_correo BEFORE INSERT ON examen_final
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF correo IS NULL THEN
    SET new.correo = 'jatuesta@mail.com');
END IF; 

END //
```

Comment: Should be `new.correo` in the `IF` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New.crreo should be tested also for empty strings

> ```
> CREATE TABLE examen_final (correo varchar(199), nome varchar(100))
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER tr_i_correo BEFORE INSERT ON examen_final
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>
> IF NEW.correo IS NULL OR NEW.correo = '' THEN
>     SET new.correo = 'jatuesta@mail.com';
> END IF; 
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO examen_final VALUEs (NULL, 'test1'), ('', 'test2')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM examen_final
> ```
>
> ```
> correo            | nome 
> :---------------- | :----
> jatuesta@mail.com | test1
> jatuesta@mail.com | test2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3105a02dddae24380b2f1967350c0e5c)*